# Leave only the elements that are not repeated in a given list. Ex: (a b a a a c c) gives us (a b)

Tags: c++

So i need to be able to do this in c++. what i was able to do is using "abaaacc" as a string and i got the right answer, but i don't know how to solve it when "a b a a a c c" are in a linked list. can someone help me with a code:

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int SIZE=20;
int main ()
{
    int numbs[SIZE], value, idx,n;
    cout<<"PLease enter size of an array"<<endl;
    cin>>n;
    cout << "Please enter in a series of numbers "<<endl;
    for(idx = 0; idx < n; idx++)
       cin >>numbs[idx];


    cout<< numbs[0] << " ";
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    bool matching = false;
    for (int j = 0; (j < i) && (matching == false); j++)if (numbs[i] == numbs[j]) matching = true;
    if (!matching) cout<< numbs[i] << " ";
}   

}
```

now i want it to remove the duplicate adjacent and give me 1 copy of it

like the ex but using numbers so how can i be able to edit my code to do that.

Comment: I guess people can help you with the code - post the code and they can suggest how to fix it...

Comment: the problem is i dont do well using linked list, i did it when they were a string but not as a list

Comment: The usual procedure is: You try to solve it on your own. You get stuck. You can ask a specific question.

Comment: oh i see, its my first time here and so i dont know

Comment: No problem, you can add your attempt to solve this to the post and try to get this question re-opened.

Comment: there is my code , thats the most i can try :/

Comment: now how can i reopen the question? XD

Comment: Now you need to find/wait for 4 more users to vote to reopen the question. Until then you can try further. Maybe have a look at [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). You can use it as a automatically growing array for building the output. But, what kind of linked list were you talking about initially?

Comment: its a single link list, i will try though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some time and so I tried to solve this.

It is indeed a tricky thing. You need to take care of the edge cases first and last item, and 1-2 item lists. 
In between you need to iterate with three iterators at the same time to find the unique item in the middle of these subsets. And as you are dealing with a list, you need to work around the missing random access iterators.

I'm more used to Python these days, where complex iteration is comfortable and you can get away with zips and slices nicely in this case. Maybe the new [ranges](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) could have been used to nicen up this code. Maybe I'll try this some time.

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

std::list<char> remove_adjacent_duplicates(std::list<char> input) {
    std::list<char> output;
    std::list<char>::iterator first = input.begin();
    if (first == input.end()) {
        // no first, item, exit
        return output;
    }

    // let second point to second element
    std::list<char>::iterator second = input.begin();
    ++second;
    if (second == input.end()) {
        // no second item, insert first, then exit
        output.push_back(*first);
        return output;
    }

    // check first item
    if (*first != *second) {
        // first and second are different, insert first
        output.push_back(*first);
    }

    // let third point to third item
    std::list<char>::iterator third = input.begin();
    ++third; ++third;
    // check items up until the last
    while (third != input.end()) {
        if (*first != *second && *second != *third) {
            // the second item neither equals the first, nor the third
            // insert second
            output.push_back(*second);
        }
        // increment iterators
        ++first; ++second; ++third;
    }

    // finally, check the last item
    if (*first != *second) {
        // the last two items differ, insert the latter
        output.push_back(*second);
    }

    // done
    return output;  
}

void test_case(std::list<char> l) {
    std::list<char> output = remove_adjacent_duplicates(l);
    for (char i : l) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << " -> ";
    for (char i : output) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    test_case({'a'});
    test_case({'a', 'b'});
    test_case({'a', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'});
}
```

The output is:

```
$ g++ test.cc -std=c++11 && ./a.out
a  -> a 
a b  -> a b 
a b a a a c c  -> a b
```

Comment: thank you alot for the effort, i was able to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough. First you [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) the container and then you use [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) (combined with `erase`) to remove all but one instance of each value.

Comment: OP wants to remove duplicates by **pair**, that requires a custom `unique`.

Comment: Well, you could sort a `std::vector` of `std::reference_wrapper` initialized from the list. Or just construct a vector from the list, do the work and then construct a new list (if one insists on a list).